# Mule Performing a string manipulation

Tags: mule

What is the best way to perform a string manipulation. I wish to perform a substring on a email address to extract the domain detail and populate this to a variable.
a java transformer is a possibilty, but i was hoping if i could use a message enricher with a expression to perform this operation.
pardon me but i am still a greenhorn on Mule.

here is the excerpt from my mule flow which is failing with error cannot resolve method string length.

```
 <enricher target="#[flowVars['FromAddressDomain']]" doc:name="Message Enricher"> 
        <expression-transformer expression="#[ payload.fromAddr.substring(payload.fromAddr.lastIndexOf('@')+ 1,payload.fromAddr.lenth())]" doc:name="Expression"></expression-transformer>  
    </enricher>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use:

```
<set-variable variableName="FromAddressDomain"
     value="#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.substringAfter(payload.fromAddr, '@')]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dataweave transform on payload and use the operator splitby and spilt on @ character. Please take a look at below link for more information on splitby operator

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/dataweave-operators#split-by

Comment: You should take into consideration that your answer is next century answer. In four years a lot has happened and I don't see that knowledge being reflected in your answer. Please include it somehow.